# Apply filter based on type of variable while creating dynamic HTML table columns with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a dynamic HTML table with the following data:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = [{
    id: 201,
    text: "Some Text",
    date: new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00")
  }, {
    id: 202,
    text: "Other Text",
    date: new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00")
  }];

});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Text</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="items in data">
      <td ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image]

But I want to apply a date filter every time the inner ng-repeat encounters a date type, but not when it encounters any other type (like string). I checked out some already available solutions but not able to apply them on this case.

[Here is the Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/rishabh1990/5tgksqLf/)

Comment: this works there `<td>{{item.date | date}}</td>` see updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/imraqes/7k3h9fra/1/

Comment: But I need to specify the <td> dynamically using ng-repeat, and not every individual item as <td> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the `date` filter is the easiest solution. As you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), it will only apply to dates anyway:

> Returns
>   string
>   Formatted string or the input if input is not recognized as date/millis.

So this is valid:

```
<td ng-repeat="item in items">{{item | date}}</td>
```

Even if `item` is not a date.

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb5v1aru/).

**Update**

Since you also have numeric values, I think there has to be something less generic in the code, to check if the current field should be treated as a date.

Consider the following:

```
<td ng-repeat="(key, item) in items">{{isDate(key) ? (item | date) : item}}</td>
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.isDate = function(key) {
    if (key === 'date') {//add more conditions if necessary
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9kLtu5f/)

Comment: This solution will fail if there is a numeric variable in the object like ID. It will convert everything to date, including numeric.